# How to create drop down while the menu structure is in array type?

Tags: theming, routes

I have created menus with sub-menus in the header.

It is supported by some themes .

But some themes don't support this. e.g Bartik, fontfolio etc.

I want to use the drop down as customized in the main-menu region, so as to display in these themes also.

How can I edit this in the drupal page.tpl?

As I am new to drupal, please suggest me.

E.g Dropdown not Supported in this format:

```
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'menu',
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'menu'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      )));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found some possible answers related to your solution.

**SOLUTION 1:**

The main menu in Bartik only displays the first level. Since it's hardcoded in `page.tpl.php` there's nothing you can do about it.

Here's how to get the menu to work properly:

1. In your theme settings (admin/appearance/settings/bartik) disable "Main menu".
2. Go to admin/structure/block and add the "Main Menu" block to the header region (or wherever you want it).

Alternatively, you can also check out the excellent [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, which generates extra customizable blocks (1st level, 2nd level, etc) for each menu.

**SOLUTION 2:**

There are some useful resources that may help you to solve your problem.

- [How to create a drop down menu in bartik theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2297065)
- [Drupal 7 + Bartik + Dropdown for Main Menu Children](https://www.drupal.org/node/1026036)
- [Add drop down menu support to Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/node/1508652)
- [Drupal Responsive Bartik Theme with Dropdown Menus](http://www.garypratten.co.uk/content/drupal-responsive-bartik-theme-dropdown-menus)